Error: @rnmapbox/maps native code not available
I'm trying to render a Mapbox map in my react native app. I've followed the docs https://rnmapbox.github.io/docs/install and everything went fine but when calling the actual library in my component it throws this error:
Android Bundled 3643ms (node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js)
 ERROR  Error: @rnmapbox/maps native code not available.
 Make sure you have linked the library and rebuild your app. See https://rnmapbox.github.io/docs/install?rebuild=expo#rebuild, js engine: hermes

The prebuild went without any issue:
npx expo prebuild --clean

✔ Would you like to proceed? … yes

✔ Cleared android, ios code
✔ Created native directories
✔ Updated package.json | no changes
✔ Finished prebuild
✔ Installed CocoaPods

Here is the app.config.ts
import { ConfigContext, ExpoConfig } from 'expo/config';

module.exports = ({ config }: ConfigContext): ExpoConfig => {
  return {
    ...config,
    name: 'hot2eat',
    slug: 'hot2eat',
    version: '1.0.0',
    orientation: 'portrait',
    icon: './assets/icon.png',
    userInterfaceStyle: 'light',
    splash: {
      image: './assets/splash.png',
      resizeMode: 'contain',
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    },
    updates: {
      fallbackToCacheTimeout: 0,
    },
    assetBundlePatterns: ['**/*'],
    plugins: [
      [
        '@rnmapbox/maps',
        {
          RNMapboxMapsDownloadToken: process.env.MAPBOX_SECRET_KEY,
        },
      ],
      [
        'expo-build-properties',
        {
          ios: {
            useFrameworks: 'static',
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
    ios: {
      supportsTablet: true,
      bundleIdentifier: 'com.hot2eat.app',
    },
    android: {
      adaptiveIcon: {
        foregroundImage: './assets/adaptive-icon.png',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      },
      package: 'com.hot2eat.app',
    },
    web: {
      favicon: './assets/favicon.png',
    },
  };
};


"@rnmapbox/maps": "^10.1.24"
"react-native": "0.73.6"
"expo": "~50.0.14"

Am I missing anything? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Nevermind, I just need to build the app after running the prebuild command:
npx expo run:android

Which is somemehow missing in the docs.
